# Admob's callback not firing everytime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, callback, admob

I made an app in Swift with SwiftUI framework and SwiftUI App life cycle.

I use that class to manage the interstitial ad:

```
class Interstitial : NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, UIApplicationDelegate{
    var interstitial : GADInterstitialAd?
    
    let adUnitID: String = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910"
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        loadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func loadInterstitial(){
        let request = GADRequest()
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: adUnitID, request: request) { [self] (ad, err) in
            if(err !=  nil){
                print(String(describing:err?.localizedDescription))
            }
            else {
                interstitial = ad
                interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
            }
        }
    }
    
    func showAd(){
        let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        if interstitial != nil {
            interstitial!.present(fromRootViewController: root!)
        }
        else {
            nc.post(name: Notification.Name("UserClosedAd"), object: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("ad closed")
        nc.post(name: Notification.Name("UserClosedAd"), object: nil)
        return
    }
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        print("ad failed to be presented")
        nc.post(name: Notification.Name("UserClosedAd"), object: nil)
        return
    }
    func adDidPresentFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        print("ad presented")
        return
    }
}
```

and I show the ad in this way:

```
let pub = NotificationCenter.default
        .publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("UserClosedAd"))
var interstitial : Interstitial = Interstitial()

var body: some View {
    Button(action:
            {
                self.interstitial.showAd()
            }) {
        Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
            .foregroundColor(.red)
        Text("Show ad")
    }
    .font(.system(size: 30, weight: .semibold, design: .rounded))
    .padding(30)
    .onAppear(perform: {
        interstitial.loadInterstitial()
    })
    .onReceive(pub, perform: { _ in
        newView = true
        print("Ad closed")
    })
}
```

The problem is that sometime the callback work, but other not. When I use the app on a real device, or simulator, that is not connected to Xcode, the callback never works.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance,
Onnwen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try following:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @ObservedObject var interstitial: FoolGADInterstitial = FoolGADInterstitial(adUnitId: "xxxx")

    var body: some View {
        Text("123")
            .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
    }
    
    func onAppear() {
        #if PLUSVERSION
        #else
        guard manager.shouldShowInterstitialAd else { return }
        interstitial.showAd()
        #endif
    }
}

class FoolGADInterstitial: NSObject, GADFullScreenContentDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var adUnitId: String = ""
    var interstitial : GADInterstitialAd? = nil
    
    init(adUnitId: String) {
        super.init()
        self.adUnitId = adUnitId
        loadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func loadInterstitial() {
        GADInterstitialAd.load(withAdUnitID: adUnitId, request: GADRequest()) { [weak self] (ad, err) in
            if let err = err {
                foolPrint("load error, \(err.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.interstitial = ad
            self.interstitial?.fullScreenContentDelegate = self
        }
    }

    func showAd() {
        guard let ad = self.interstitial, let root = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController else { return }
        foolPrint("showAd done.")
        ad.present(fromRootViewController: root)
    }
    
    func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd) {
        foolPrint("Ad dismissed")
        loadInterstitial()
    }
    
    func ad(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd, didFailToPresentFullScreenContentWithError error: Error) {
        foolPrint("present failed, \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

and FYI: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/blob/master/Swift/admob/InterstitialExample/InterstitialExample/ViewController.swift

Comment: Thanks you very much, that's works, but only when I click the button for the second time. At the first time callbacks never work... do you know what that might be?

Comment: Because ads will take time for downloading from admob. you can retry if self.interstitial = nil after 0.2s.